# Google Maps API Autocomplete input textbox value lost

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I have added a Google map on a webpage, It also has a Textbox with Google maps Autocomplete. User can add a marker on the map by clicking on the map or typing a location address in the Autocomplete textbox. If user clicks on the map a marker is added on the map and the address of the location is shown in the Autocomplete Textbox.

Code:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&region=LK&libraries=places"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<input id="inputLocation" name="inputLocation" type="text">

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(6.9182471651737405, 80.70556640625),
            streetViewControl: false
        };

        var autocompeteOptions = {
            componentRestrictions: { country: "lk" }
        };

        var map;
        var locationMarker;

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        function initialize() {

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

            //Add marker when user clicked on Map
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {

                var location = event.latLng;

                if (locationMarker) {
                    locationMarker.setMap(null);
                }

                geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': location }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        if (results[1]) {

                            //locationMarker
                            locationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: location,
                                map: map
                            });

                            document.getElementById('inputLocation').value = results[1].formatted_address;

                        } else {
                            alert('No results found');
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
                    }
                });

            }); //click

            var autocompleteInput = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('inputLocation'), autocompeteOptions);

            //Autocomplete place Changed
            google.maps.event.addListener(autocompleteInput, 'place_changed', function () {

                autocompleteInput.bindTo('bounds', map);

                locationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map
                });

                var selectedPlace = autocompleteInput.getPlace();
                if (!selectedPlace.geometry) {
                    return;
                }

                if (selectedPlace.geometry.viewport) {
                    map.fitBounds(selectedPlace.geometry.viewport);
                } else {
                    map.setCenter(selectedPlace.geometry.location);
                    map.setZoom(17);
                }

                locationMarker.setPosition(selectedPlace.geometry.location);

                var locationAddress = '';
                if (selectedPlace.address_components) {
                    address = [
                      (selectedPlace.address_components[0] && selectedPlace.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                      (selectedPlace.address_components[1] && selectedPlace.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                      (selectedPlace.address_components[2] && selectedPlace.address_components[2].short_name || '')
                    ].join(' ');
                }

            }); //From place_changed

        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    });
</script>
```

This works fine on computer web browser, but when I test it on a mobile device (Galaxy S III, iPhone 5, ...) it's not working as expected (on actual device and on Chrome emulator).

If I first click on the input Textbox and then click on the map it adds the marker on the map and displays the address in the input Textbox, but then if I click somewhere on the page, address Textbox value is lost. (This happens only if the text box is focused before clicking on the map)

Is there anything I can do to fix this issue?

Comment: The same behaviour on FF: information in textbox is lost. There is no any message in console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commented by     Anto Jurković , this also happens in FF.

**You may observe a difference:**

When it works as expected the input doesn't have the focus. When it fails the input will not lose the focus when you click on the map.

**The reason:**

The autocomplete internally listens to `focus` and `blur`. When you click somewhere on the page(not the map) the autocomplete will lose the `focus` and the `blur`-listener of the autocomplete will be triggered .

The `blur`-listener will set the value of the input to the `name`-property of the current place. The current place will be stored internally based on the result of a Autocomplete-request(which is empty in this case).

The autocomplete will not notice changes of the value of the input(as applied by you programmatically), it only listens to the <kbd>key</kbd>-events of the input.

**So what you can do is:**

Remove the focus from the input(either in the `click`-callback of the map or before you set the value of the input):

```
 document.getElementById('inputLocation').blur();
```